# Python class with dynamic __iter__ function

Tags: python, oop, iterator

I would like to create a Python class which should have a dynamic iterator function. That is, I would like to send the iterator function as a parameter instead of hardcoding it inside the class.

Here is an example class:

```
class fib:   
    def __init__(self, items, iter_function):
        self.iter_function = iter_function
        self.items = items

    def __iter__(self):
        self.iter_function(self.items)
```

with two example iterator functions:

```
def iter_func(items):
    for item in items:
        yield item

def iter_func2(items):
    for item in items:
        yield item*2
```

When I create an object with the following, I get an error:

```
a = fib([1,2,3],iter_func)
next(iter(a))
```

The error prints as:

```
----> 1 next(iter(a))

TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: probably `def __iter__(self):
    self.iter_function(self.items)` => `def __iter__(self):
    return self.iter_function(self.items)`

Comment: You've missed the `return`  at `self.iter_function(self.items)` line. But besides that you'd better to modify the `__next__` method instead of `__iter__`.

Comment: It is interesting. I thought that it should simply execute the given function which should then create a generator. Thanks.